# effective caching sql database tables data with regular intervals in asp.net with azure redis cache

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, sql-server-2012, redis-cache

We are developing a search engine which requires high speed api results to give the quick results.
We are using **Asp.Net MVC** as a front end and **Web API** is the layer between database and MVC application.

Each search query requires 20 to 30 tables merged data in order to give the api result. To avoid this, i am trying to cache the database data during regular intervals(every 5 minutes). But, this will becomes overload to database.

Please do suggest the best way to cache database data in an efficient manner

Regards,
Mallikharjun

Comment: Which database you are using?

Comment: Azure SQL Server 2012